# How to simply get the BooleanField of a model which is True if and only one can be true at all in Django?

Tags: django

I have the following model which has two boolean fields. Due to my logic, they won't be both true at anytime. How can I get the field which is `True` in a simple straight forward way?

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    poller = models.ForeignKey(Poller, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vote')
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    poller_choice_one_vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    poller_choice_two_vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Vote by {self.user}'
```

This is how I'm doing it right now:

```
    voted_for = Vote.objects.get(poller_id=poller_id, user=request.user)

    is_true = voted_for.poller_choice_one_vote
    is_also_true = voted_for.poller_choice_two_vote
    
    if is_true:
        voted_for = voted_for.poller_choice_one_vote
    elif is_also_true:
        voted_for = voted_for.poller_choice_two_vote
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: So exactly what do you want to return? `1` or `2`?

Comment: I want to return the str/name of the field that is True

Comment: What do you want to do? Your code just stores `True` in `voted_for` if any of the boolean field is set to true else it just stores the vote object. Why don't you just _write_ the string down: `if is_true: voted_for = "poller_choice_one_vote"` if the field name is what you want??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps to use the meta to get the name of the field:

```
voted_for = Vote.objects.get(poller_id=poller_id, user=request.user)

one = voted_for.poller_choice_one_vote
two = voted_for.poller_choice_two_vote

if one:
    voted_for = Vote._meta.get_field(one)
elif two:
    voted_for = Vote._meta.get_field(two)
```

Comment: But this doesn't include the case where both are False

Comment: @Jonas I changed the code now. See if it works.

Comment: upvoted cause it is a working solution, but rly doesn't simplify my approach. Let's see for other solutions to come up :)

Comment: And what exactly is `_meta.get_field(True)` supposed to give you? As `one` or `two` have that value, when you call that...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat **one** or **two** is a reference to the fields, when passing them to `_meta.get_field()` it will return the field instance so you can access the name and other meta data. Read the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/meta/

Comment: `voted_for` is a `Vote` instance when you write `one = voted_for.poller_choice_one_vote`, `one` then has the value the field `poller_choice_one_vote` has for that instance which can be either `True` or `False` since it is a `BooleanField`, I have read the documentation, perhaps _you_ should have a look at it first.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yes? I know it is a Vote instance initially, but when you use the get_field method and re-assign you get the _field_ instance and not the entire Vote instance.

Comment: @Jonas `Vote._meta.get_field(voted_for.poller_choice_one_vote)` fails with `FieldDoesNotExist: Vote has no field named 'True'` so I'm not sure how it would work